# CONCAT columns within a file

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I'd like to concatenate `column2` until `column4`.
Example (first.txt):

```
|ID|column2|column3|column4|
|1 |  a    |    b  |   c   |
|2 |  d    |    e  |   f   |
```

To this (mynewfile.txt) :

```
ID|column2
1 | a b c 
2 | d e f
```

This is my script in cygwin : `$ awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4 }' first.txt > mynewfile.txt`

Of course, it is not working out well.. How do I improve the script?

Comment: `awk` uses whitespace as the default field deliimter. You need to use the `-F` option to change it to use the pipe as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the field separator so that a pipe with optional whitespace around it is the field delimiter.

The pipe at the beginning of the line causes an empty field 1 before the pipe, so the ID is field 2, and columns 2-4 are fields 3-5. So it should be:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' 'NR == 1 {print "ID|column2|"} NR > 1 {printf("%d | %s %s %s |\n", $2, $3, $4, $5)}' first.txt > mynewfile.txt
```

Comment: The ID column went missing

Comment: it works for me on OS X. I don't have Cygwin, but I don't see why it would be any different.

Comment: the `column2` is in `ID` column now. it should be merged together with the rest

Comment: I tried it with both GNU Awk 4.0.1 ON Debian, and Awk 20070501 on OS X, and it worked correctly. I don't know why it's not working in Cygwin.

Comment: Do your lines really start with a pipe as you show?

Comment: How was I supposed to know that? I thought that was the real file format, and that's what my script works with. Edit the question and show what the file really contains.

Comment: I even explained what I was doing in the answer, did you read: **The pipe at the beginning of the line causes an empty field 1 before the pipe**. Why do I bother giving detailed explanations if you're not going to read it?

Comment: You changed the output file, the input file still has pipe delimiters. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, it still have pipe delimiter. In case I need to open on excel

Comment: `$ awk -F' *\\| *' 'NR == 1 {print "ID|column2"} NR > 1 {printf("%d | %s %s %s \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5)}' first.txt > mynewfile.txt` This works for me now. Updated some items. Thank you!

Comment: If the input file starts with `|` then my field numbers are correct, I don't understand why you're able to start with `$1`.

Comment: I think i just shot in the dark? Since `$2` was on `ID` where it supposed to be in `column2`. I tried to add `$1` and removed delimiters as you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Not especially general *GNU* `sed` method:

```
sed 's/^[|]//;1s/2.*/2/;1!{s/|/ /g2;s/ */ /2g}' first.txt
```

Output:

```
ID|column2
1 | a b c 
2 | d e f
```